# Search api excerpt are empty in the result

Tags: 8, search

I have installed search api module in drupal 8 and included excerpt in the search result.

But excerpt are always empty in the search result. (HTML div element is there but no content inside)

I searched in the forum and enabled the 'highlights' from settings as suggested. 
But no changes in the result (I cleared the cache)

Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First go to this path 
**admin/config/search/search-api/index/default_index/processors#edit-processors-highlight-settings**
make sure this settings are enabled

[image]

Next i created a view Global search which has search Excerpt field.

[image]

Finally i was able to see the highlighted text word after searching

[image]

Actually this is not default search form that comes in drupal8 it is exposed form in block if you see in view exposed form setting i have enabled it.
once this is done, exposed form comes in block just place that in which ever regions you want.

Answer (score 1):

Go to /admin/config/search/search-api/index/**INDEXNAME**/processors and click "highlight". Do not forget to include the exerpt in your view fields.

[image: Check "Highlight"]

[image: include the exerpt in your view fields.]

Answer (score 0):

Let me summarize the question anno 2021:

1. Create a Solr server + Default Solr content index (/admin/config/search/search-api)
   [image: solr server + index example]
2. Edit your server (/admin/config/search/search-api/server/**your_default_solr_server**/edit). Open the advanced tab and select:Retrieve result data from Solr, Retrieve highlighted snippets

[image: solr highlighted snippeds drupal 8]

3. Edit your index and select the datasources (/admin/config/search/search-api/index/**your_default_solr_index**/edit)
4. Add fields to search into. If you created a content type that exists of paragraphs or custom blocks. Be sure to add those fields in this section to get a result. (/admin/config/search/search-api/index/**your_default_solr_index**/fields)

[image: solr and paragraphs]

4. Go to the processors section inside the search index (admin/config/search/search-api/index/**your_default_solr_index**/processors)
   Select 'highlight' and scroll down to the page to enable settings.

[image: index processors solr highlight]

Select your preferences:
[image: solr index processor highlight settings]

5. Create a view and add the "Search:Excerpt" into the fields section:

[image: solr highlight excerpt in view]

Answer (score -1):

These days this config variable is at:
/admin/config/search/search-api/index/default_solr_index/processors
where "default_solr_index" is the machine name of your index.

The checkbox you want is called "Highlight"